Prevent escaping quotes in Thymeleaf attribute value
I'm trying use Thymleaf template to display html page that looks like this:
<html>
  <body>
    <my-webcomponent data='{"foo":"bar"}' ></my-webcomponent>
  </body>
</html>

The variable part that I want to change is in the data attribute, it's a JSON string, which I would like to be held inside single quotes, so that I don't need to replace all double quotes with escaped replacements &quot;
Additionally I would like to have a template that is easily previewed on browser offline as a file, so I don't need to run a webserver each time I update a file. Thymeleaf makes this with attribute replacements so that you can keep a static (sample) version at the same time (i.e. I can use both th:data and data attributes)
I tried using this:
<my-webcomponent th:data='${jsonData}' data='{"foo":"bar"}' ></my-webcomponent>

but Thymeleaf keeps escaping them.
How can I achieve that?
As a sidenote, I don't have access to the webcomponent code, I have to use it as is.
EDIT
It seam that question is not clear enough for some of the readers, let me make you a simple code that illustrates the behavior:
A simple springboot java controller:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class Demo {

    record FooBar(String foo) {}


    @GetMapping(value = "/demo", produces = "text/html")
    public final String enter(Model model) throws JsonProcessingException {
        FooBar fooBar = new FooBar("bar");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String foobarAsString = mapper.writer().writeValueAsString(fooBar);
        model.addAttribute("foobar", foobarAsString);
        return "demo.html";
    }

}

A html template file:
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<body>
<my-custom-tag th:data="${foobar}"> </my-custom-tag>
</body>
</html>

a command that shows what I get from the server:
$ curl http://localhost:8080/demo
<html lang="en">

<body>
<my-custom-tag data="{&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;}"> </my-custom-tag>

</body>
</html>

Please let me know if the question is still not clear enough.

shouldn't your outer quotes be " ? As in <my-webcomponent data="{'foo':'bar'}" ></my-webcomponent>

@cyberbrain JSON standard allows using only double quotes and at the other hand XML standard allows using both single and double quotes for attributes, so that's why I've chosen to use in such way.

What exactly do you mean by "keeps escaping them" and how exactly is that a problem?

Yeah this comes up a lot... I don't think there is a way to control this behavior, and I don't think its a problem in most cases.

Asfar as i know passing attributes shouldn't add escape characters. It's probably in the my-webcomponent where you use it that they are added. You would need to post the code for said component to be able to help with that though,

@deceze please see the updated answer with sample response

@Ralan please see the updated answer with sample code. Note that you don't need any my-webcomponent code to reproduce it.

{&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;} in HTML means {"foo":"bar"}. Where is the problem with this encoding?

@deceze my question is how can I achieve not to have these escaped quotes (as they tend to be ugly especially in larger JSONs) but rather to look as shown in first code sample in my question.

@Ralan is there any reason this question should be still closed for not being clear enough?

I suppose it's clear what you want, but it's not clear why you want it. Is it just an aesthetic thing, or does the encoded value actually produce a problem downstream?

@deceze let's say it is just an aesthetic thing. But I can't see how this detail will help to answer the question, which is how can I achieve this?

In that case I'd say that it's not worth the time trying to "fix" this at all. You must properly encode values anyway if you don't want HTML injection/syntax errors. Whether there may be a somewhat more minimalist encoding possible than the one being applied is fairly insubstantial.

@deceze The first example in the question displaying the what I want part is also perfectly legal html code

Sure, never said otherwise. I just wanted to know whether the encoding Thymeleaf applies by default is actually causing a problem or not. Because then we could've tried fixing that problem. Because as is, there's nothing wrong with how Thymeleaf encodes stuff. The only thing is that you'd simply prefer it to do in an alternative way. And while that's a legitimate question per se, I'm not sure I'd personally spend any time trying to solve it vs. just accepting how it's done.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Maybe this will help, give a try for [( )]. From thymeleaf docs: [(...)] corresponds to th:utext and will not perform any HTML-escaping.

Thanks for the idea, I tried   and it throws TemplateProcessingException
